# R: SAS (if/then statement )in R

Tags: r

I was working previously with SAS and then decided to shift to R for academic requirements reasons.
My data (healthdemo) are health data containing some health diagnostic codes (ICD-10), I want to separate these codes into different columns. This is part of str(healthdemo):

```
$ PATIENT_KEY     : int  7391510 7404298 7390196 7381208 7401691 7381223 7383005 10188634 7384574 7398317 ...
 $ ICDCODE         : Factor w/ 1125 levels "","H00","H00.0",..: 654 56 654 654 665 48 90 679 654 654 ...
 $ PATIENT_ID      : int  39387 50244 38388 27346 49922 27901 27867 61527 33186 45309 ...
 $ DATE_OF_BIRTH   : Factor w/ 14801 levels "","01/01/1000",..: 7506 10250 52 73 94 6130 85 2710 95 100 ...
```

the ICDCODE contains many diseases from H00 to J99; first, I separated the letters from numbers in the ICDCODE

```
healthdemo$icd_char = substr(healthdemo$ICDCODE,1,1)
healthdemo$icd_num = substr(healthdemo$ICDCODE,2,2)
```

then I created diseases columns by this function:

```
healthdemo$cvd = 0
healthdemo$ihd = 0
healthdemo$mi = 0
healthdemo$dys = 0
healthdemo$afib = 0
healthdemo$chf = 0
```

now I want to apply a function similar to this SAS function (that I used to use):

```
if icd_char = 'I' and 01 <= icd_num < 52 then cvd = 1;

if icd_char = 'I' and 20 <= icd_num <= 25 then ihd = 1;

if icd_char = 'I' and 21 <= icd_num <= 22 then mi = 1;

if icd_char = 'I' and 46 <= icd_num <= 49 then dys = 1;

if icd_char = 'I' and icd_num = 48 then afib = 1;
```

this function will assign each patient with the given ICD character and ICD-number into cvd=1 (e.g.) and so on.

I tried using these functions in R but they didnt work for me:

```
healthdemo$cvd[healthdemo$icd_char == 'I' & 01 <= healthdemo$icd_num 
      & healthdemo$icd_num < 52 ] <- 1
```

and this

```
if (healthdemo$icd_char == "I" &  01 < = healthdemo$icd_num < 52  )
   {healthdemo$cvd <- 1}
```

Would somebody help me please ?

Comment: Your first approach (`healthdemo$cvd[healthdemo$icd_char == 'I' & 01 <= healthdemo$icd_num & healthdemo$icd_num < 52 ] <- 1`) should work. Did you get an error?

Comment: there is no error shown, but all the results in column cvd where =1 even if the character is J or H !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar struggle when I transitioned from SAS to R for health-related research.  My solution was to, as much as possible, let go the "if...then" approach and take advantage of some of R's unique native programming capabilities.  Here are two approaches to your problem.

First, you can use indexing to find and replace elements.  Here is some hospital discharge data of the kind you describe:

```
hosp<-read.csv(file="http://www.columbia.edu/~cjd11/charles_dimaggio/DIRE/resources/R/sparcsShort.csv",stringsAsFactors=F)
head(hosp)
```

Say I want to identify every birth-related diagnosis in Manhattan.  I first create a logical vector that returns a series of TRUES and FALSES for my search criteria, then I index my data frame by that logical vector.  In this case I am also restricting the columns or variables I want returned:

```
myObs<-hosp$county==59 & hosp$pdx=="V3000 " #note space
myVars<-c("age", "sex", "disp")
myFile<-hosp[myObs,myVars]
head(myFile)
```

The second, and perhaps more computationally elegant, approach is to use a function like "grep".  Say you're interested in identifying all substance abuse diagnoses, e.g. alcohol abuse (291, 303, 305 and sub-codes), opioids, cannabis, amphetamines, hallucinogenics, and cocaine (304 and related sub-codes), or non-specific substance abuse-related diagnoses (292). In SAS you would write out a long if-then statement (or a more efficient array) of some kind:

```
#/*********************** SUBSTANCE ABUSE *****************/
#if pdx in /* use ICD9 codes to create diagnoses */ (’2910’,’2911’,’2912’,’2913’,’2914’,’2915’,
#   ’29181’,’29189’, ’2919’,’2920’,’29211’,’29212’,’2922’,’29281’,’29282’,’29283’, #........etc....,’30592’,’30593’)
#Then subst_ab=1; 
#Else subst_ab=0;
```

In R, you can instead write:

```
substance<-grep("^291[0-9,0-9]|^292[0-9,0-9]|^303[0-9,0-9]|^304[0-9,0-9]^305[0-9,0-9]", hosp$pdx)
hosp$pdx[substance]
hosp$subsAb<-"No"
hosp$subsAb[substance]<-"Yes"
hosp$subsAb[1:100]

table(hosp$subsAb)
plot(table(hosp$subsAb))

library(ggplot2)
qplot(subsAb, age,data=hosp, alpha = I(1/50))
```

Tomas Aragon has written a wonderful introduction to R for epidemiologists that goes into these approaches in detail. (http://www.medepi.net/docs/ph251d_fall2012_epir-chap01-04.pdf)

Comment: thank you very much ,,that is really useful..especially the book,,I will download it now.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of IF ... THEN >>> in SAS is achieved by the use NOT of if(...){...} but rather of ifelse(..., ..., ...). And you cannot use the form `a < var < b`. Furthermore you have not quite gotten the functional paradigm of R programming.

Try this instead your last statement:

```
healthdemo$cvd <- NA   # initialize to missing
healthdemo$cvd <- ifelse (healthdemo$icd_char == "I" & 
                           01 <= healthdemo$icd_num &
                           healthdemo$icd_num < 52 , 1, healthdemo$cvd )
```

Note that the form: `var <- ifelse(logicalvec, value, var)` allows you to do selective replacements. The old value is the default and only the "parallel" value of TRUE in the logical vector triggers a change.

Robert Muenchen has written a book entitled something along the lines of 'R for SAS and SPSS Users'. There's also a freely available draft version that about 70 page long that should show up with a web search.

Comment: I agree, Im still a beginner in R,, but I loved it more than SAS,,

Comment: the function you provided returns some error:

healthdemo$cvd <- ifelse (healthdemo$icd_char == "I" & 
+   01 < = healthdemo$icd_num &
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"healthdemo$cvd <- ifelse (healthdemo$icd_char == "I" & 
  01 < ="
>   healthdemo$icd_num < 52 , 1, healthdemo$cvd ) 
Error: unexpected ',' in "  healthdemo$icd_num < 52 ,"

Comment: The error comes from the fact that I just copied your inequality expression that had a space in it. Remove the space from "< =". Tested answers are available when test data is provided, .... by the questioner. Learn to use dput(head(data, 20)) to provide reasonable sized test data.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is du to `icd_num` not being numeric.

Use the following command to create this variable:

```
healthdemo$icd_num <- as.numeric(substr(healthdemo$ICDCODE, 2,
                                        nchar(healthdemo$ICDCODE)))
```

(If you want to get rid of the numbers after the `.`, replace `as.numeric` with `as.integer`.)

Then your first approach should work:

```
healthdemo$cvd[healthdemo$icd_char == 'I' &
               01 <= healthdemo$icd_num &
               healthdemo$icd_num < 52 ] <- 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the [icd](https://cran.r-project.org/package=icd) package to solve this kind of problem. You can use standard groups of diseases, or create your own. It can then quickly plough through all your codes and assign disease groups to each patient. It works with ICD-9 and ICD-10 codes.

I found plain text processing (like `grep` in previous answer) was both slow and unreliable. ICD codes have numerous variations in how they are recorded, e.g. an ICD-9 code like `X91.9` is equivalent to 0919. String processing for hundreds of thousands of rows was far too slow for me using R functions efficiently, so I wrote the package using a lot of C++, so bigger data users can assign comorbidities to a million patients in a couple of seconds. Hope this helps.